# using numpy where results from one array to another

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I have two numpy arrays - both generated from the same main array.  one is  generated from a slice of the main array and the other is from a where clause.  the problem I am having is that when I get the indices from the where clause and apply it to the second array, I get an error:  only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index. I've tried converting the array using transpose and using just the row portion of the where result, but still with the same issue.

```
y=np.empty([0,24])
#y array is filled with records

z[:,0]=y[:,1]
z[:,1]=y[:,2]
z[:,3]=y[:,3]

#...(total of 24 columns in y and I only use 6 in the z array)
#some data calcs from y
ar = np.array(y[:,7] - y[:,8]) #PVExport
ar = [maxamount if i > maxamount else i for i in ar]
ar = [0 if i < 0 else i for i in ar]

#where clause - get all false values in column 6. the 
#here is where the error happens
naList=np.where(y[:,6]==0)


ar[naList[0]]=maxamount

z[:,4]=ar
```

when the above line executes - I get the error only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.

when I try something similar by filling an array in the interactive window it seems to work.

looking to fill the 4th column of that z array with the results of some data calculations in the y array.  any help is appreciated

Comment: `ar` is a list, not an array.  Also check `y`. That (0,24) shape is odd..  What does `naList` look luke?